# Holomorphic Map $r: D \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $r(z)^k = z$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D \subset \mathbb{C}$ be a disk and $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Furthermore, suppose $0 \notin D$. How can I show that there exists a holomorphic function $r: D \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $r(z)^k = z $ for all $z \in D$?

I would appreciate any hint on how to approach this!

Comment: define a branch of the logarithm on your disc (simply connected not containing zero) and then $r=\exp((\log z)/k)$

Comment: Such function does not exists for $k\ge 2.$  See answers for $k=2.$ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1799448/holomorphic-function-with-fz2-z The main point is that $r(0)=0$ hence $z=0$ is a root of order at least $k$ for $r(z)^k.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc: Here it is assumed that $0 \notin D$!

Comment: @Conrad It's also not clear to me why exp((log z)/k) should be holomorphic.

Comment: @MartinR Do you admit  $\{0<|z|<1\}$ ? That case was discussed at the link from my comment.

Comment: It is a composition of holomorphic functions as $\exp$ is entire and $\frac{\log z}{k}$ is holomorphic on your disc since $\log z$ is

Comment: @Ryszard the result in op holds on any simply connected domain that doesn't contain zero - a punctured disc is not simply connected - more generally we can always define $z^s$ on such domains for any complex $s$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc: Here $D$ is assumed to be a *disk* that does not contain the origin.

Comment: @Conrad In that case the problem is easy as you mentioned in your previous comment. The conclusion is true for any domain  disjoint with  a  half-line connecting the origin and Infinity,.